# write an primitive testclass

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, before-trigger

I am new to apex, and I dont know how to correctly write a Testclass for my trigger.

---

Trigger has to update field Time_Zone__c of object Task according to Time_Zone__c of object Contact, which is associated with object Task with WhoId  field  [image: Object task]
Here is the code:

```
trigger TaskTimeZoneUpdate on Task(before insert, before update){
  set<id>setwhoIds = new set<id>();

  for (Task objTask : trigger.new) {
    if (objTask.WhoId != null) setWhoIds.add(objTask.WhoId);
  }

  map<id, Contact> mapContact = new map<id, Contact> ([Select 
  c.Time_Zone__c, c.Id From Contact c where id in :setWhoIds]);

    for (Task objTask : trigger.new){ 
      if (objTask.WhoId != null && mapContact.get(objTask.WhoId)!=null) 
        objTask.Time_Zone__c = mapContact.get(objTask.WhoId).Time_Zone__c;
    }

}
```

Looking forward your response, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll find useful documentation here https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers.
The task you want to perform however could be done with Process Builder and doesn't need code at all.